# How to quit the entire suite for Functional testing?

Tags: intern

How do I quit the entire suite for Functional testing?  I have 'setup' and then run through the different tests but would like to stop tests within suite; don't continue next test if I see condition.  Currently, next test is ran if assert.

For instance:

```
// suite variable ??
var suiteFail = false;

registerSuite({
    name: 'Test Suite',

    setup: function () {

        //console.info('\n In setup');
        remote = this.remote;
        remote.setWindowSize(1024,768);
    }, // complete setup

    beforeEach: function () {
        if (suiteFail) {
            // stop suite ??
        }
    },

    'test1': function () {
    // set suiteFail true if condition 
    }

    'test2': function () {
    // set suiteFail true if condition 
    }
```

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception from `beforeEach` or `afterEach` will cause the suite to fail, and any remaining tests will not be executed, so you could do something like:

```
beforeEach: function () {
    if (suiteFail) {
        throw new Error('Failing suite because X');
    }
}
```